# Is is possible to embed UUID into PDF/A file using iText library?

Tags: pdf, itext, uuid, xmp, pdfa

My program produces a multiple-pages PDF/A files using iText API. I have two problems about this: 
1.I have no idea that the PDF file does not come with both "xmpMM:DocumentID" and "xmpMM:InstanceID" tags in root metadata. I tried to add both tags into root metadata by XmpMMSchema, but it seems like doesnot support the field 'xmpMM:InstanceID'. 
2. I think iText generates UUID for each PDF/A file, right? Is there a way to extract it out?

Does anyone here know how to do that?

Comment: Each PDF can (ISO 32000-1) or should (ISO 32000-2) have an ID that consists of a pair of identifiers. For a newly created PDF, both identifiers of the pair should be identical. For a "manipulated" PDF, the first identifier should be identical to the first identifier of the original PDF, and the second identifier should be different. iText creates or adapts the ID of a PDF according to this rule. Knowing this, can you rephrase your question, because I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for helping me! My question is how can I extract this ID from the PDF, and add it into PDF's root metadata? I know how to modify root metadata, and I could not find the way for extracting ID or assign a new ID. I have a PDF/A file sample produced by Adobe Abocrot, which has two fields "DocumentID" and "InstanceID" in root metadat. So I am trying to find a way to do so. But I only found DocumentID in XmpMMSchema. Could you show me a simple example to do this kind of manipulation?